# Adding CSS/JS files to Html file not working

Tags: html, css, flask

Sorry this question might look a little bit ugly but I am new to web dev.

I try to add some css/js files into my html and here is the structure.
May I understand where I get wrong for the path?
Thanks

[Here is the stucture layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdB8d.png).
I have tried `href="../assets/css/ud-styles.css"` but still not working

Comment: Where is located your .html file ?

Comment: Try using href="assets/css/ud-styles.css" if index.html file exists in same folder where assets folder exists.

Comment: @Dolotboy it's under the folder of `templates`

Comment: @Xie so if I am correct the tree is something like mainFolder which container templates and assets (And maybe so more but it's not important), am I right ?

Comment: @MuhammadBilal No, `index.html` under folder `templates`, while `.css` under foler `assets/css`. `templates` and `assets` are under same folder

Comment: @Dolotboy Yeah, you may refer to https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdB8d.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In jinja2 templates that flask uses you need a "static" folder for you styles.
So you need to create a folder named "static" beside your template folder, inside this "static" folder you create a folder named "style" move the css folder inside this new "style" folder which is inside "static" and you link it using this:

```
<link rel= "stylesheet" type= "text/css" href= "{{ url_for('static',filename='style/css/ud-styles.css.css') }}">
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, lifesaver